# ethclient.Client in go-ethereum unit testing

Tags: unittesting

I am using [backends.SimulatedBackend](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum@v1.10.3/accounts/abi/bind/backends#SimulatedBackend) in unit testing.

however, `backends.SimulatedBackend` is not compatible with [ethclient.Client](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient#Client).

Any one can advise how to create a `ethclient.Client` in unit testing? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

check this out..

[Use backends.SimulatedBackend and ethclient.Client synonymously](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103112/use-backends-simulatedbackend-and-ethclient-client-synonymously/130424#130424)

Probably the following package helps with what you try to achieve...

https://github.com/bonedaddy/go-defi/blob/main/utils/blockchain.go

At line 12 at the comments it says:

> // Blockchain is a generalized interface for interacting with the ethereum blockchain
>
> // it satisfies all functions required by the ethclient, and simulated backend types.
>
> // **This allows you to use ethclient and the simulated backend interchangeably which is**
>
> // **particularly useful for testing**

You could try to use exactly this "Blockchain" interface or treat the `backends.SimulatedBackend` and the `ethclient.Client` sperately (as it should be).