# Use backends.SimulatedBackend and ethclient.Client synonymously

Tags: clients, unittesting

[backends.SimulatedBackend](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum@v1.10.3/accounts/abi/bind/backends#SimulatedBackend) and [ethclient.Client](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient#Client) seems can be used synonymously, according to [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/23148).

However, `ethclient.Client` doesn't implement [Commit](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/aa637fd38a379db6da98df0d520fb1c5139a18ce/accounts/abi/bind/backends/simulated.go#L108), thus it cannot replace `backends.SimulatedBackend`.

Then another attempt is wrapping `backends.SimulatedBackend` into `ethclient.Client`. Any method can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this library and especially the utils package:

https://github.com/bonedaddy/go-defi/blob/main/utils/blockchain.go

At line 12 at the comments it says:

> // Blockchain is a generalized interface for interacting with the ethereum blockchain
>
> // it satisfies all functions required by the ethclient, and simulated backend types.
>
> // **This allows you to use ethclient and the simulated backend interchangeably which is**
>
> // **particularly useful for testing**

You could try to use exactly this "Blockchain" interface or treat the `backends.SimulatedBackend` and the `ethclient.Client` sperately (as it should be).